# Bash script, that for each user checks if they have password, homedir exists and group is valid

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i need to make a script for college but i dont have the time to understand how to make one due to the overwehlming work i have to do, i wont even have crismas holydays :(.
So im here to ask for help.

I need to make a script that for each entry (user) in /etc/passwd checks if the user as a password, if his homedir exists and if his group is valid ( exists)
If it dosent follow a condition i should write it in /tmp/auth_errors. Theres no specification as to what i should write in case of failure, so a simple thing will be enought.

I have been looking around and i saw many examples of checking if there are users without password, but ussualy this examples are one liners and i would need to check each user again for the group and for the homedir condition, and i dont know how to do it.

Im pretty experienced in programming but this bash scripting is making me confuse with things like arrays, grep, etc.

Would love if you could help me so i may rest a bit this chrismas, else im afraid i wont.

Thanks all.

EDIT: some lovely soul helped me. however he didnt include the part to verify if user has password so i searched around and came up with this. Meanwhile im not able to test it, need to wait for teacher to fix the VM

```
while IFS=: read -r user pass uid gid info home shell
do
  if[[ $(passwd -status "$uid" | awk '{print $2}') = NP ]]  **HERE
  then
  echo "$uid dosent have a password."
  fi
  [ -d "$home" ] || echo "$user is missing home dir $home"
  getent group "$gid" > /dev/null || echo "$user has invalid group id $gid"
done < /etc/passwd >> /tmp/auth_errors
```

Do you think this will work? mainly the part of the "if[[ $(passwd ...." till the "fi" ?

Comment: It's hard to help when you don't know what you don't know. Stackoverflow is a bad place to _learn_ programming, it's rather a good place for when you already know programming and can't solve specific hard problems. I recommend [this bash guide on bashfaq](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)

Comment: thanks, i know its hard to help me since i dont know basicly anything about it. Sorry for asking such question i would trya nd learn but i'm kinda desperate.

Comment: You need space after `if`.

Answer (score 1):

> how to make a for loop that each cycle will take a single userID from passwd (need to discard to other columns in passwd) into account so i can use that userID to verify the things i need).

`/etc/passwd` is a simple file with fields separated by `:`. A simple `while read` loop would be enough:

```
# see man 5 passwd, I might mixed smth
while IFS=: read -r name pass uid gid comment home interpreter; do
    # do something with uid
    echo "Hello to $name with uid=$uid!"
done < /etc/passwd
```

For more examples see [bashfaq how to read a file field by field](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and see [man 5 passwd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html).

Comment: thank you, thats a big help to start with :)